# Stateless web services

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm wanting to make an Asp.Net MVC app, but before I start on non-UI stuff I need to get my head around this.  If I have some web services, and they are stateless, is it necessary to pass in the currently-logged-in user as a parameter to service calls?  Or does WCF have a mechanism that can handle this for me?  Or is it better to keep security in the UI layer and not worry about permissions in the services?

Comment: You should always worry about permissions on your services. Any web service can be called without using a UI as long as the URL is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check :

- [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx)
- [Security Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx)
- [patterns & practices Improving Web Services Security Guide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Does it matter that the user won't have Windows credentials?

Comment: @Inuyasha check client credential types, it is not mandatory to use windows as client credential type, see here for more details :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WCF has the solution for your problem.  Herez the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731814.aspx